# Passing an NSArray as a parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to get JSON data loaded from a `NSURLConnection` delegate to send the array of objects back to the tableview that called it.

The delegate object is initialized with `callback` to send back to

```
NSArray *returnArray;
ResultsTableRoot *callback;
```

JSON handling method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
    returnArray = [json objectWithString:responseString 
                                   error:&error];
    [responseString release];

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Send data back to table view
    [callback resultsArrayReciever:returnArray];
}
```

The array can't be accessed from here, the tableview I want to have the information, however the method is called

```
-(void)resultsArrayReciever:(NSArray *)array {
    // Code executed    
    if(array) {
         // Code never executes, array isnt there
    }
}
```

If you have a better way to go about this whole thing, it is more than welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the NSError instance to see if there wasn't some problem while deserializing the JSON;
2. Try retaining the object:

   ```
   NSError *error;
   SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
   returnArray = [[json objectWithString:responseString error:&error] retain];
   [responseString release];
   [callback resultsArrayReciever:returnArray];
   [returnArray release];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The `returnArray` is probably autoreleased. Try retain/releasing it in your methods.

If it is autoreleased the contents will be released in your run-loop and therefore disappear by the time you want to access it.